# Server side OAuth2 in Dart

Tags: oauth-2.0, dart, google-oauth

There are a lot of examples of how to use OAuth2 in Dart client-side (in browser), but I can't find any example of how to implement authentication for server-side.

For example, for Node.JS there are frameworks like [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) but I can't find anything similar for Dart.

As a use case could be a not SPA project, and I need to provide login to Google/Facebook/Twitter/etc

Can anybody provide any snippet using raw `dart:io` `HttpServer` or any server-side frameworks like [Start](https://github.com/lvivski/start) or [Bloodless](https://github.com/luizmineo/bloodless) ?

Comment: The readme of the package now includes some demo code http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oauth2

Answer (score 2):

The description says client library but also that it only works with 'dart:io' which means it is for the server
http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oauth2

and

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_oauth2_v2_api (client and server)

Comment: Unfortunately first library relies on client - it shows popup, and handle client callbacks.

For server-side OAuth2 you need to ask server to do a callback to some URL (that you can configure), so there quite server-side specific code for supporting of handling there callbacks. 

Even during registration in Google Developers Console there is absolutelly different dialogs for client and server side auth credentials.

Comment: This is weird because it states on the readme that it requires 'dart:io' and therefore it can't be used on the client. I asked about it here https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/LKkhs2TPJjo I keep this answer up-to-date when I get feedback.

Comment: I know that oauth is different on client and server and the first library is definitely server side. (I guess you don't want to build an Oauth provider but want offer clients to use other oauth providers to authenticate on your server.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a complete OAuth2 implementation for the [Angel](https://angel-dart.dev) framework:
https://github.com/angel-dart/oauth2

The included code abstracts over the OAuth2 transport itself; the storage, database, etc. is up to your choice.